# AlarmManager Issue AlarmApp

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a question about alarmmanager, i had made simple alarm app before and it succesed, but i try to make it again with more function. But my pendingintent of alarmmanager never be call so my alarm never ring on. 
This is my code when called that function with tooglebutton when ischecked

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(toggleButton.isChecked())
    {
        sts = 1;
        alarmDb = new TorasanDatabaseAdapter(context);
        alarmDb.open();
        alarmDb.updateAlarm(alarm._id,sts);
        alarmDb.close();
        Alarm.talarm.setText("aaaaaaaa");
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("id", alarm._id);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("sound", alarm.sound);
        PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, alarm._id, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar AlarmCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentstatus = sts;
        alarm.status = currentstatus;
        Log.i("ID", " alarm hour: " + alarm.hour + " minute: " + alarm.minute+" status:"+alarm.status);
        AlarmCal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        AlarmCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm.hour);  // set user selection
        AlarmCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarm.minute);        // set user selection
        AlarmCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmCal.getTimeInMillis(),pendingAlarmIntent);
    }
```

MyAlarmService.java

```
public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

   public void onCreate() {
      Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      return null;
   }

   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
      super.onStart(intent, startId);
      Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
      String sound = extras.getString("sound");
      int hour = extras.getInt("hour");
      int minute = extras.getInt("minute");
      int id = extras.getInt("id");
      int status = extras.getInt("status");
      int statusdone = extras.getInt("statusdone");
      int statusdelete = extras.getInt("statusdelete");  
      Toast.makeText(this, "asadsadasdad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      Log.i("ID"," H="+hour+" M="+minute);
      Intent alertIntent = new Intent();
      alertIntent.setClass(this,DisplayNotifications.class);
      alertIntent.putExtra("sound", sound);
      alertIntent.putExtra("id", id);
      alertIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      startActivity( alertIntent );       
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The PendingIntent you pass to AlarmManager must be for BroadcastReceiver use. You've passed a PendingIntent for Service use.

The AlarmManager won't start a Service for you. All it will do is send a broadcast intent.

**EDIT: Add code example:**

Replace

```
PendingIntent.getService()
```

with

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast()
```

Comment: i use this for references http://blog.nelsondev.net/?p=124 and he used getService, in my old alarmapp it no problem, but in my new app i got a problem